# Remove reversal pairs - ms access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

My question is similar to, but not the same as [Remove reversal pairs using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401393/remove-reversal-pairs-using-sql). The situation is as follows. Data (no typos. Two rows relate to X1 and reversals do have the same REF):

```
ROW      |    REF     |    Amount |    Comment      |
1        | 00001      |    1000   | Relates to X1   |
2        | 00002      |     500   | Relates to X1   |
3        | 00003      |     100   | Relates to X2   |
4        | 00004      |    1000   | Relates to X3   |
5        | 00004      |   -1000   | Reverses 00004  |
6        | 00005      |     250   | Relates to X3   |
```

Desired outcome

```
ROW      |   Agg_Amt |    Comment      |
1        |    1500   |      X1         |
2        |     100   |      X2         |
3        |     250   |      X3         |
```

### Problems:

The following successfully removes reversals but loses important information

```
SELECT REF, SUM(Amount) FROM T1 GROUP BY REF
```

The following produces 2 lines for X3, one amounting to 1250 and one to -1000

```
SELECT REF, Comment, SUM(Amount) FROM T1 GROUP BY REF, Comment
```

Any other solution I tried leads to one of the two above problems, so it is pointless to share.

I have solved the problem using `WHERE REF NOT IN` , but performance is sub-optimal to say the least.

#### Edit

Full code:

```
SELECT Comment, SUM(Amount)
FROM T1
WHERE REF NOT IN(
     SELECT DISTINCT REF 
     FROM T1
     WHERE Comment Like "Reverses*")
GROUP BY Comment
```

Being MS-Access I cannot use a temp table.

### Question

Is there an elegant solution to this, preferably without too much wrapping and nesting? I know I am probably missing something simple here.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use a normal Access table as temp table. Just `SELECT INTO` before and `Docmd.DeleteObject` after. Or keep it, and do `INSERT` and `DELETE` accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a double aggregation:

```
SELECT Replace(T1.Comment, 'Relates to ', '') AS [Comment]
       , SUM(agg.SubAmount) AS Agg_Amt
FROM T1
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT REF, SUM(Amount) AS SubAmount
    FROM T1 
    GROUP BY REF) agg
ON agg.REF = T1.REF
WHERE INSTR(T1.Comment, 'Reverses') = 0
GROUP BY T1.Comment
```

Comment: Sorry, paused to rethink and 5 mins went by. Just note that ReversesT1 does not exist as a table. Otherwise works fine. Initially didn't notice that you sum agg.subamount on top.  Also, the INNER JOIN could have ```GROUP BY REF HAVING SUM(Amount) > 0```, if one wants to fully eliminate reversals as opposed to showing them as 0. I think this would also allow for ```SUM(Amount)```, instead of ```SUM(SubAmount)```

Comment: Correct on both points. Fixed the incorrect table name. Glad I could help. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this might do what you want:

```
select t1.comment, sum(amount)
from t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from t1 as tt1
                  where tt1.ref = t1.ref and
                        tt1.amount = - t1.amount and
                        (t1.comment like "Reverses*" or
                         tt1.comment like "Reverses*"
                        )
                 )
group by t1.comment;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this doesn't improve performance from ```where ref not in```. I added the full code in the question above